# Como remuevo clases según el tamaño del navegador

Tags: javascript, css3

Lo de arriba, tengo una sidebar que cuando le doy a un botón le agrega una clase para que esta se oculte, lo que quiero hacer es que si la sidebar esta oculta cuando el usuario redimensione el navegador por ejemplo a menos de 980px la sidebar siga oculta removiendo la clase que hace que esta se muestre.

Comment: ¿qué has intentado?

Comment: Hola leonardo. Lee sobre media queries. Intenta ver si eso es lo que quieres y si encuentras alguna dificultad, edita la pregunta para añadir más detalles. Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ocultar un elemento según el tamaño de la pantalla puedes usar los `mediaqueries` son una propiedad de css, el `@media screen` te permiten editar los estilos de las clases según el tamaño de la pantalla.

Ocultar un elemento cuando el ancho del navegador es de 500px de ancho o menos. [Ejemplo tomado de w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

```css
.example{
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .example {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="menu example">
  <h1>SOLO ME VERAS A MÁS DE 500px</h1>
</header>
<p> Reduce o Agranda esta pagina</p>
```